# Routing for Wordpress Multisite with both subdomain and subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory, multisite

New to WordPress but finally got close to what i want. What I wanted was to use multisite with both sub domains and sub directories.

What i did:
- I setup wordpress multisite with subdomain option.
- I setup my domainname to allow wildcard subdomains
- I use the standard htaccess file for subdirectories (this fixed a css issue to diaplay sites with both subdomains and subdir correctly)
- After I create a new website I go to edit and add a subdirectorie to the url

The result:
The above steps allowed me to create websites like the list below:
- domain.com
- sub1.domain.com
- sub1.domain.com/en
- domain.com/en
- ...

The problem:
All the websites display correctly, but the admin url for urls that have both sub domain and sub directories doesn't seem to work (eg. "sub1.domain.com/en/wp-admin/").

The solution?:
I think it can easily be fixed in the htaccess, mainly with changes to the standard line below:

> RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

Does anybody know how to rewrite the above line so the wp-admin can be accessed by domains that have both subdomains and subdirectories? Keep in mind that it also has to work for domains that only have a sub domain or sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

since the above might not be possible I ended up working with the plugin WP Multi Network https://nl-be.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/ .
Now I can create a network per subdomain which is also a multisite then i can create subdirectory sites per subdomain. All users are shared across all sites/networks.